# why is my Macbook pro(2015) stuck on loading screen after Disabling SIP?

Tags: macos, catalina, permission

I was trying to change some system files in my macbook pro and tried to make the system folders writable, first I disabled my SIP in recovery mode by

```
csrutil disable
```

and then I booted and ran these in the terminal

```
sudo mount -uw /
```

```
sudo chmod 777 *
```

on the target folder to make the directory writeable but it didn’t work, though I checked the permissions of the folder and they changed to Read/Write for all groups but, I wasn’t able to make the changes in the folder.
After that when I gave up and re-started the mac, its stuck on the apple logo loading bar.
I was able to go into recovery mode and enabled SIP and repaired the volumes and the container but I still can’t boot, its stuck on the loading screen.

Is there any way to solve this without reinstalling a fresh copy of catalina on my mac?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I'd recommend that you restore a recent backup to get your Mac running again.